# window.attachEvent doesn't seem to be working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

Top page:

```
...
<script>
if (window.addEventListener) {
 // addEventListener equivalent of code below
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
 window.attachEvent("message", function(e) {
  if (e.origin != "page2.html") { return; }
  alert(e.data);
 });
}
</script>

<iframe src="page2.html"></iframe>
```

page2.html:

```
<script>
var message = "hello!";
parent.postMessage(message, '*');
</script>
```

This code works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Of course IE has its own way of doing things so this code doesn't work despite using its own `.attachEvent`.

The page2.html is actually a page on another domain; I'm sending the correct P3P headers (shouldn't matter, but there's that).

How do I find out why `postMessage` doesn't seem to be reaching the parent page?

Answer (score 11):

`attachEvent` takes its event name in the form `"onmessage"`, as opposed to `addEventListener` (which uses `"message"`)

Comment: …and it uses `window.event` instead of the `event` parameter.

Comment: switched first param to "onmessage"... didn't seem to help. what am I missing here?

Comment: See @MarcelKorpel's comment, older IE uses `window.event`. A common catch-all is `e = e || window.event`

Comment: I've added the tidbit you just wrote at the start of function(e) and it's still not working.

Comment: Thank You very much, this answer helped me after searching for more then 1 hour!